# Matplotlib set colors

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm new to matplotlib. 
I have this code that draws a line

```
 plt.plot(linex, liney, 'r')
```

I want to change 'r' to an arbitrary rgb value of my choice. It seems like and easy task by I can't figure it out by myself.

Answer (score 2):

`plt.plot(linex, liney, color = (R,G,B))`

where R,G,B go from 0->1

for more options see the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/api/colors_api.html)